# Can metadata become a target variable in Orange3?

Tags: anaconda, widget, metadata, data-mining, orange

I have a column of metadata, I am unable to directly drag and drop it in the target variable box in "Select Column" widget in Orange. Is there a way to make metadata as my target variable?

Comment: Is it a numeric or categoric variable? Yes. Text (string)? No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target variables can only be numeric or categoric.

For text variables try the Create Class widget, which converts text variables to categoric.

Comment: Thank you! Since my text variable is too diverse, it is hard to use the Create Class widget, as there are too many unique values which cannot be put in a general class; it is very tedious to do so. I tried changing the "type" and "role" to "categorical" and "target" respectively in the File widget, I will find out how this works. Anyway this is just for exploration purpose and Create Class widget is a great solution, thank you!